# In Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome), how can we view/edit app launcher properties?

Tags: gnome, launcher

In Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome), how can we view/edit app launcher properties? I have some snap-installed apps for which I'd like to take a look at the launcher properties. Also, how do we create launchers for the gnome desktop manually, if we know the name and location of the executable?

Comment: By the way, yes, I know that I can go into Settings/Applications and view and change some of the settings on various apps. But this utility doesn't seem to have the granular level of control I'm looking for, and it doesn't provide a way of creating new desktop launchers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a GUI way you can create and manage all your apps launchers, this utility is called "MenuLibre"

It is on Ubuntu Repos

```
sudo apt install menulibre
```

this app will appear under gnome apps once installed

[image: MenuLibre Screenshot]

Here is the [Link](https://bluesabre.org/menulibre/) to MenuLibre official Website